# WPF Edit Resource Dictionary dynamically passing parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a style defined in my resource dictionary so the style can be used in all  over my application.

```
<Style x:Key="HyperlinkStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Color3}" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Color3Pressed}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Color2NotEnabled}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I use the style in Datagrid like this :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="140*"  CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="True" Header="">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate />
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource DatagridCellHyperlinkStyle}">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=MyObject, Converter={StaticResource ConverterMyObject}}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                    <TextBlock Width="Auto" Height="Auto" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
                                            <Hyperlink IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}">
                                             <InlineUIContainer TextDecorations="{Binding Path=TextDecorations, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}}" Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}}">
                                              <ContentPresenter Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Content="{Binding DataContext.MyObject.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                                             </InlineUIContainer>
                                                <Hyperlink.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="Hyperlink" BasedOn="{StaticResource HyperlinkStyle}">
                                                                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="Clic" />


                                                        </Style>
                                                </Hyperlink.Style>
                                            </Hyperlink>
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This works great but I would like to be able to have 2 colors in my style depending on a parameter.

For example, my datagrid has 1500 rows, I want to highlight 100 rows from the collection by changing their hyperlink color.

So I thought the best was to set the Tag property of the hyperlink to a custom value and use it in the style. Following this answer : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3424267-ed1f-4b30-90a1-5cca9843bd22/problem-making-a-trigger-on-the-tag-property?forum=wpf, I made the changes below :

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

First I've set the tag manually for each row to see if the style changes :

```
<Hyperlink IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}" Tag="10">
```

and added this trigger to my hyperlink's style:

```
<Trigger Property="Tag">
            <Trigger.Value>
                <sys:Byte>10</sys:Byte> <!-- My highlighted object -->
            </Trigger.Value>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Color1}" />
        </Trigger>
```

But it doesn't work when I launch my application (I still have "Color3" whereas I want "Color1" when Tag is equals to 10.
I've checked the output there isn't any error.

I've tried to change "sys:Byte" by "sys:String" but the result was the same.

Do I need to change my approach for this problem ? I've read maybe we can't add trigger on Tag Property.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest if you set the tag like this

```
<Hyperlink IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}" Tag="10">
```

Then write the trigger in the same way:

```
<Trigger Property="Tag" Value="10">
   ...setter
</Trigger>
```

Or if in hyperlink you use Byte type as Tag:

```
<Hyperlink IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}">
    <Hyperlink.Tag>
       <sys:Byte>10</sys:Byte>
    </Hyperlink.Tag>
</Hyperlink>
```

Then same goes in the trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="Tag">
    <Trigger.Value>
       <sys:Byte>10</sys:Byte>
    </Trigger.Value>
   ...setter
</Trigger>
```

Comment: It seems that there is an error with my cell's template, I can have the color if I bind to relative Source = Hyperlink (and not textblock) but if I do so I lose all mouseOver properties for my Hyperlink. Why when my hyperlink is hovered it doesn't go in the "IsMouseOver" trigger of its style ?